# Is there a way to change the Lego NXT sensor polling frequency?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming, nxt-g

I am using LEGO NXT 2.0 with the native NXT flowchart-style programming environment, I would love to be able to poll the sensors more frequently. (In particular, it seems that the light sensor is polled very infrequently, only about once or twice per second, and this limits the speed of a line-following robot I can build)

Is there a way to change the LEGO NXT sensor polling frequency using the LEGO software?

I am looking for a way to do this **using the LEGO software**, I realize that there is a way using MS robotics.

Answer (score 3):

> Most sensors have the capability of sending you notifications or updates as the value of their sensor changes. This is accomplished by repeatedly contacting the NXT brick and querying the sensor. The polling frequency allows you to configure for each sensor how often this is done.
>
> In most cases, you may leave this value set to 0, which indicates the default polling frequency. However, there may be times when you wish to get sensor reading back from one sensor more often. In this case, you can adjust the polling frequency, which is specified in milliseconds (1/1000 second).

[from Device Services: Microsoft Robotics on **msdn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870566.aspx)

The article goes on to suggest the range within which this can be effective.

Comment: But that's using Microsoft Robotics, **not** the native NXT programming environment, right?